# Using variables in simple fields (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using simple fields for wordpress but when I use variables in the options of the command, it does not work, only if I use the value ...

```
$pid="34343";
$field_value = simple_fields_value('pname1', $pid);
print_r($field_value);
```

I tried:

```
$pid="34343";
$field_value = simple_fields_value('pname1', {$pid});
print_r($field_value);
```

and

```
$pid="34343";
$field_value = simple_fields_value('pname1', <? echo $pid ?>);
print_r($field_value);
```

Need help for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [**DOCS**](http://simple-fields.com/documentation/api/getting-values/simple_fields_values/) Simple field value 2nd parameter to be `int`

**simple_fields_values**

> simple_fields_values – Get one or several repeatable simple fields
>   values from a post.
>
> This works the same way as simple_fields_value but it returns an array
>   with all values since it retrieves all values from repeatable field
>   groups.

Description

```
mixed simple_fields_values( string $field_slug [, int $post_id, mixed $options] )
```

So use this solution :

```
$pid = "34343";
$field_value = simple_fields_value('pname1', (int) $pid);
print_r($field_value);
```

OR

```
$pid = 34343;
$field_value = simple_fields_value('pname1', $pid);
print_r($field_value);
```

Comment: $field_value = simple_fields_value('pname1', (int) $pid); worked ... i dont understand why i need (int) to make it work ...

Comment: as per the documentation functions require integer value from the 2nd parameter there must a work around to return post when only integer value comes. i never use simple fields but why not try with documentation first :) so it did the trick

Answer (score 0):

**simple_fields_value()**

**retrieve** one or several fields values from a post

```
$field_value = simple_fields_value("myFieldSlug");
echo $field_value;


$field_value = simple_fields_value('pname1');
echo $field_value;
```

Here you can use

```
$post_id=34343;
$field_value= simple_fields_value("simple_field_slug", $post_id);
```

Comment: yes but i want to retrive from other custom post (id:34343)

Comment: visit http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188065/get-simple-field-value-with-post-id